# How would I create a React application that keeps track of characters' status for writing a story?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, mapping

I have been working on a project to try and make a react application that displays the chapter along with the characters stats.

**Chapters list is stored globally inside App.js.
Chapters list should display the text at index 0 (first chapter)
When I press the next button, the list should iterate to display text at index 1 (second chapter)**

Issue: I suspect because I initialized a map, all of the items within the array is listed
(displays all chapters upon init)

I followed Traversy Media's tutorial to try an get an understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

I have a **const nextPage** which is supposed to change the chapter.

```
const nextPage = () => {
      setChapters(
        chapters.map((chapter) => chapter.id === count ? {...chapter, visible: !chapter.visible} : chapter
        )
      )
      console.log('prevpage')
    }
```

I also have a chapter class (displaying text)

Also a chapters class (to map the contents)

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import { useState } from 'react'

import Header from './components/Header'
import Characters from './profiles/characters'
import Chapters from './chapters/chapters'
import Characters1 from './characters_timeline/characters1'

var count = 1

function App() {
  const [chapters, setChapters] = useState(
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        chapNum: 1,
        text: "Mock chapter1 : qwertyuiop qwertyuiop sdfghjkl; sdfghjk cvbn dfghj dfghj dfghj dfghj fdghj rtyui cvbn jk lhj kl gh df sd fsdfsdsdfwertertyuio ertyuifghgftghfghj",
        visible: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        chapNum:2,
        text: "Mock chapter2: sadasdasdasdasd asdasssssssssdasdasd yui cvbn jk lhj kl gh df sd fsdfsdsdfwertertyuio ertyuifghgftghfghj",
        visible: false
      }
    ]
)

    const nextPage = () => {
      setChapters(
        chapters.map((chapter) => chapter.id === count ? {...chapter, visible: !chapter.visible} : chapter
        )
      )
      console.log('prevpage')
    }

    const prevPage = (id) => {
      console.log('prevpage', id)
    }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header onNext={nextPage} onPrev={prevPage}/>
      <Chapters chapters={chapters}/>
      <Characters1/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Chapters.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Chapter from './chapter'

const Chapters = ({chapters, onNext}) => {

return (
    <>
      {chapters.map((chapter) => (
      <Chapter key={chapter.id} chapter={chapter} onNext={onNext}/>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}


export default Chapters
```

Chapter.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Chapter = ({chapter, onNext}) => {
  return (
    <div className='chapter' onClick={onNext}>
      <h3>{chapter.text}</h3>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Chapter
```

Goal state:
[Goal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4GUS.png)
[React app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Fft.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for reading!